# How to solve ORA-00917: missing comma error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to insert data with a datetime in the table and the query given below:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (ITEM_NUMBER, ORGANIZATION_CODE, RECORD_STATUS, FILE_DESCRIPTION, ATTACHMENT_CATEGORY, FILE_NAME, TRANSACTION_TYPE, FILE_PATH, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, CREATION_DATE, RECORD_ID) 
VALUES (10000, org, NEW, wre, Item Internal, ZPDF001_1.pdf, CREATE, /media/, TO_CHAR('07-Jan-24 20:00:21','DD-MON-YY:HH24:MI:SS'), TO_CHAR('07-Jan-24 20:00:21','DD-MON-YY:HH24:MI:SS'), '602')
```

This code throws an error:

> missing comma at column 243.

I tried `TO_DATE` also, but that did not work either.

Comment: It looks like you need to quote your strings

Comment: `values (10000,'org','NEW','wre','Item Internal','ZPDF001_1.pdf','CREATE','/media/',TO_CHAR('07-Jan-24 20:00:21','DD-MON-YY:HH24:MI:SS'),TO_CHAR('07-Jan-24 20:00:21','DD-MON-YY:HH24:MI:SS'),'602')`  If you don't include quotes around your strings, your database will believe them to be objects (tables, views, columns, procedures, databases, etc) and that will throw all sorts of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using TO_CHAR which is for convert a date to a string, and in that case you're trying to insert a date, so you must use TO_DATE:
Can you try this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (
    ITEM_NUMBER,
    ORGANIZATION_CODE,
    RECORD_STATUS,
    FILE_DESCRIPTION,
    ATTACHMENT_CATEGORY,
    FILE_NAME,
    TRANSACTION_TYPE,
    FILE_PATH,
    LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
    CREATION_DATE,
    RECORD_ID
) VALUES (
    10000,
    'org',
    'NEW',
    'wre',
    'Item Internal',
    'ZPDF001_1.pdf',
    'CREATE',
    '/media/',
    TO_DATE('07-Jan-24 20:00:21', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),
    TO_DATE('07-Jan-24 20:00:21', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),
    '602'
);
```

Or there might be a problem with the date format too!

Answer (score -1):

It's seems like the issue is with the `TO_CHAR` function format. The correct format should be 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS' without the colon between 'YY' and 'HH24'. So the correct query should be:

```
Insert into TABLE (ITEM_NUMBER,ORGANIZATION_CODE,RECORD_STATUS,FILE_DESCRIPTION,ATTACHMENT_CATEGORY,FILE_NAME,TRANSACTION_TYPE,FILE_PATH,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,CREATION_DATE,RECORD_ID) values (10000,org,NEW,wre,Item Internal,ZPDF001_1.pdf,CREATE,/media/,TO_CHAR('07-Jan-24 20:00:21','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),TO_CHAR('07-Jan-24 20:00:21','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),'602')
```

You can check the `TO_CHAR` function in the Oracle documentation here: [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)